# How to make Pydoc document my functions in a specific order?

Tags: python, pydoc

I want to specify a order in which Pydoc will document my functions. I am not sure how Pydoc orders the functions in the generated documentation -- it is surely not the textual order in the module.

This is useful because I would like to then specify my `printUsage()` function to be documented first.

```
"""
Sample module docstring
"""

def printUsage():
    """
    Command line usage: python my_module.py -i path/to/input_file.c
    If calling my_function() directly, pass the path/to/input_file.c as an arg.
    """
    print(printUsage.__doc__)

...
```

So that when a user checks out the docstring for `my_module`, he can quickly see how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [sourcecode](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/pydoc.py):

Looks like the module docs are stored as a dict, so when they iterate through them, it creates random order:

```
def namelink(self, name, *dicts):
    """Make a link for an identifier, given name-to-URL mappings."""
    for dict in dicts:
        if name in dict:
            return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (dict[name], name)
```

Comment: So, I guess a dead end? Or can something be tweaked?

Comment: If you want to edit the source code, you are welcome to.